# How to insert Datetimepicker Value in SQL Server database in custom format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, sqlcommand

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [f_present] Values   (@faculty_id, @name, @designation, @gender, @date, @status, @remarks)", con.active());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faculty_id", fIdtxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fNametxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", fDestxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", fGendertxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", comboBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", remarksTxt.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: A date is not a string. Use the DatetimePicker.Value property instead of the textual representation of that date. Moreover try to avoid the AddWithValue method as well. [It has many problems](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: have you tried adding the _date_ as... `DateTime` instead of as text?

Comment: Aside: specify column names in `insert` statement. [`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And dispose your command and connection objects with `using` blocks

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the text representation but the value.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the date parameter with `DateTimePicker` value like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: This still uses a string with a fixed format. Some SQL database might not recognize this format and will fail. If you pass a DateTime variable directly, the middleware will choose the correct format for the used database

Comment: i tried this with ("dd/MM/yyyy") but showing the same error.

Comment: @BhaskarRoy I think he uses SQL Server because he wrote `SqlCommand`. My answer should work in all SQL Server versions even if the client has different `culture` from the server

Comment: @derodevil this answer still uses the wrong type. There's absolutely *no* reason to convert the date into a string only to store it into a date-typed field. Besides, even `yyyy-MM-dd` is affected by the `DATEFORMAT`l settings when stored into a `datetime` field. The newer types `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` aren't affected but `datetime` is